# Transit in Beijing to another International flight

Tags: air-travel, transit, pek, connecting-flights

I am arriving in Beijing for a connection to Bangkok with American Airlines. My next flight is more than two hours later with another "One World Airline" Cathay Pacific. I have been told that I must collect my bags at Beijing, clear immigration and customs, and then check in again for the flight to Bangkok. This is because I have two separate tickets and, apparently, new rules were applied by airlines that with separate tickets I must clear immigration and customs.

My question is, since I only have carry-on luggage, can I simply transit through a transfer desk?

Comment: Will you have a boarding pass for the BKK flight?

Comment: Cathay do not fly from Beijing to Bangkok. Is your flight onward to Hong Kong first?

Comment: Can I ask if it worked out well (in case you did fly already)? Did you need a Chinese visa?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can simply go to your next flight in Beijing without clearing Customs and Immigration if you are carrying only hand luggage.

Good news is your next flight at Beijing airport would be through Cathay Pacific Airways and presumably you are obliged just to check in online prior to departure. All you need to do is just go to flight connection at Beijing airport and have your boarding pass ready.

I have previously traveled to Beijing and different airports with two different flight segments carrying hand luggage only.

So it doesn't matter as long as you are just carrying hand luggage, you can simply avoid Customs and Immigration and board your next flight at Beijing airport.

Comment: This seems to answer the question I'm having. However, is this valid for any company? I would be flying into Beijing with Asiana, and subsequently leaving Beijing with Aeroflot.

Comment: I'm Belgian. My wife is Korean. We would both be flying. My incoming flight is Asiana. My outgoing flight is Aeroflot. If all is good, I still have to make sure Aeroflot allows for smooth online checkin before leaving Korea. Any thoughts?

Comment: And while I'm at it, if this process works, about 2 hours between both flights should be more than enough, right? Assuming there are no delays of course.

Comment: Oh take your time. Even at the gym, you're monitoring the site, wow ;) I'll read you later then.

Comment: I just did. Thanks in advance! http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86406/transit-in-beijing-on-separate-tickets